# Is the sentence "I can match this quality no problem" grammatically correct and natural

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence "Yes, I can match this quality no problem" grammatically correct and natural when I want to answer to a person that I can achive the same quality of another person's product.

Comment: Hi Ivan, we can help with specific questions about English. If you [edit] your question to explain which part of the sentence you feel might not be correct and why, we should be able to take it off hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly idiomatic but it's not grammatically correct.

The main part of the sentence, which can stand by itself, is:

> Yes, I can match this quality.

To clarify that it's easy to do so, people often add:

> It's no problem

which is also a grammatical sentence.

However, in idiomatic speech, they tend to omit the **it's**.

And they insert the expression **no problem** either in front or at the end
of the sentence declaring that they can match the quality.

So it becomes:

> No problem, yes, I can match this quality

or

> Yes, I can match this quality; no problem!

If you were using formal speech or writing, you should say: **It's no problem**
although you will commonly hear it shortened to just **no problem!**